# Перегрузка оператора вызова ()

Tags: c++

подскажите, как перегрузить `operator()` так, чтобы индексация строк начиналась с отрицательного числа. (ну то есть чтобы я мог обращаться, например, так - `с(-2,0)`)

```
class matrix
{
    double **c;
    int m;
    int n;
}
```

часть кода на с++

Comment: На всякий случай - оператор `()` обычно дразнят оператором вызова [функции] - синтаксис выглядит так, как будто вы вызываете функцию... Оператор индексации - это `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если у вас инициализируется массив так -

```
c = new double*[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    с[i] = new double[m];
```

то все просто -

```
const double& operator()(int row, int col) const
{
    return c[row+offsetR][col+offsetC];
}
double& operator()(int row, int col)
{
    return c[row+offsetR][c+oloffsetC];
}
```

Коды проверок не выхода за границу и т.п. добавьте сами, как и внесите в сам класс поля `offsetR` и `offsetC` и их инициализацию...